# Parsing multiple arguments from the command line Node.js/js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, command-line

I'm trying to write a program that takes any number of command line arguments, in this case, strings and reverses them, then outputs them to the console. Here is what I have so far:

```
let CL = process.argv.slice(2);
let extract = CL[0];

function reverseString(commandInput) {
  var newString = "";
  for (var i = commandInput.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    newString += commandInput[i];
  }
  return console.log(newString);
}

let call = reverseString(extract);
```

I can't figure out a way to make this work for multiple arguments in the command line such as:

```
node reverseString.js numberOne numberTwo
```

which would result in output like this:

```
enOrebmun owTrebmun
```

however it works fine for a single argument such as:

```
node reverseString.js numberOne
```

Comment: Not clear what result you're trying to end up with.  Maybe `CL.join(" ").reverse()`.

Comment: `let calls = CL.map(reverseString);` then log them if you want like: `console.log(calls.join("\n"));`

Comment: You simply have to perform the operation for each item in `CL` - `for (const x in CL) { console.log(reverseString(x)) }`

Comment: you should change `return console.log(newString)` to `return newString` - `console.log` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your `reverseString()` function on each of the `argv[n...]` values passed in. After correctly applying the Array.prototype.splice(2) function, which removes Array index 0 and 1 (containing the command (`/path/to/node`) and the `/path/to/module/file.js`), you need to iterate over each remaining index in the array.

The `Array.prototype.forEach` method is ideal for this, instead of needing a for loop or map. Below is using the OP code and is the minimal program (without much refactor) needed for desired output.

```js
    let CL = process.argv.slice(2);

    function reverseString(commandInput) {
      var newString = "";
      for (var i = commandInput.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        newString += commandInput[i];
      }
      return console.log(newString);
    }

    CL.forEach((extract)=>reverseString(extract))
```

Here is me running this code from the terminal:
[image]